# POS for .Net Common Control Objects CharacterSet Compatibility issue

Tags: c#, printers, opos, pos-for-.net

I've recently purchased a Star Micronics TSP100 Printer for my "Point of Sale" application which I'm developing in C#.NET , I downloaded the POS for .Net SDK to manipulate the printer but it didn't work.

after some research I found out that I have to install monroecs CCOs in order to communicate with the printer using POS for .Net SDK.

the problem that I'm facing is that when I send Arabic letters to the printer, it prints garbage, even though the printer supports code page "1001 (Arabic)". I've tried using C# encoding and stuff but still didn't work. what exactly do you think the problem is?

Comment: Have you set-up the printer to use the Arabic letters? You should be able to change the printers character set in the configuration utility. See http://www.starmicronics.com/absolutefm/absolutefm/attachments/32/TSP100%20futurePRNT%20Software%20Guide.pdf - Under General Settings, They usually come set to US character set and have to be altered to support others.

Comment: yeah I've tried almost everything in the configuration utility, nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem in case you are having the same problem.

I set the printer to CodePage 864 instead of 1001 and I had to find out what Unicode values would print the whole set of Arabic characters to have a complete character set.

the Unicode values that you will get as a result of encoding an input word from the keyboard will not always be the same Unicode values for the printer character set, so you need to map them using switch function.